# Why do I get a bcrypt-ruby gem install error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise, bcrypt

Getting an error when trying to install the gem devise, the installation is stopping on
the gem bcrypt-ruby:

```
$ gem install bcrypt-ruby
Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I'm running OSX 10.6.7 with Ruby under RVM.
I reinstalled the lastest version of xcode & reinstalled Ruby 64bit, Rails and all the gems.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem installing under OSX 10.7.3.  When installing the gem, my error message was:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

creating Makefile

make
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1
```

Looks like the gem is looking for gcc-4.2 but I only had a file called gcc. Now since I had just installed the latest Xcode (4.3), I knew that my C compiler was compliant but the gem had gcc-4.2 hardcoded into it.  So my solution was:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

The linking worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like there might be some info missing here - for me, this was due to a brew install of gcc.  gcc was in /usr/bin, but not gcc-4.2.  So I just did the following:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.2
```

which creates a link, `gcc-4.2`, which the gem is looking for that goes back to `gcc`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

It requires to install ruby-dev before installing bcrypt-ruby.
If you are using Ubuntu, run

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

based on RUby version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using RVM & I kept having this issue whenever installing gems with native extensions (bcrypt-ruby, bson-ext, json, eventmachine, nokogiri, linecache19, etc.)

`Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

Only way I could finally get things working was to uninstall then re-install ruby.

`rvm remove 1.9.2`

`rvm install 1.9.2`

Thanks to tip from @doublebee here:
https://github.com/flori/json/issues/78#issuecomment-1499920

Answer (score 2):

You only need use rvm (ruby version manager)

```
rvm uninstall 1.9.3
```

and then

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

looks this error is on build of rvm 1.9.3, but uninstall and reinstalling fix the problem with bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Well, it works with Ruby 1.9.2 under RVM on MacOS 10.6.7:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

$ gem install bcrypt-ruby
Fetching: bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4...
```

Try `rvm notes` and see if it says you need to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 1.8 the required packages for bcrypt are in the dev bundle.  Try using

```
$sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

then

```
$gem install bcrypt-ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix work for me on ubuntu on osx use homebrew, macports whatever:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinstall bundler gem.

`gem install bundler`
and then
 `bundle install`