# rails postgresql connection could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I print

```
root@a:/home/rails/car_main# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

And get this:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"rails", "password"=>"9lDIwmajjV", "database"=>"car_main_production"}
```

So it seems like a database connection something wrong with.
It's a production digital ocean server. I used this tutorial 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean

As suggested in tutorial  I  did this to create db connection:
`cp ~rails/car_main/config/database.yml ~rails/car_main/config/`
Here is my database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: rails
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_project_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_project_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: rails_project_production
  username: rails
  password: <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

So what do I do now

Comment: I have to ask are you using the `gem 'pg'` ?

Comment: yes gem pg  and I guess I fixed it by starting postges process  ` /etc/init.d/postgresql start`

Comment: glad you got it to work